# Passing GET parameters to the default welcome controller

Tags: codeigniter

I've installed on my server new Codeigniter installation and I would like to be able to pass to the default controller (welcome) GET parameters.

For example:

http://www.myserver.com/1234

and I would like the default index function on the welcome controller will get '1234' as GET parameter, but I cant make it to work any idea?

here is my controller code:

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    /**
     * Index Page for this controller.
     *
     * Maps to the following URL
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
     *  - or -
     *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
     *  - or -
     * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
     * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
     *
     * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
     * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
     * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('welcome_message');

        // echo get parameter here = 1234
    }
}
```

And my .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller should be like this

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

/**
 * Index Page for this controller.
 *
 * Maps to the following URL
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome
 *  - or -
 *      http://example.com/index.php/welcome/index
 *  - or -
 * Since this controller is set as the default controller in
 * config/routes.php, it's displayed at http://example.com/
 *
 * So any other public methods not prefixed with an underscore will
 * map to /index.php/welcome/<method_name>
 * @see http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/urls.html
 */
public function index($number)
{
    //$this->load->view('welcome_message');

    echo get parameter here = 1234
}

}
```

Comment: U should call the controller like this :

Comment: Sorry , You should call the controller like this : localhost:8000/projectname/classname/controllername/{parameters}

Answer (score 0):

In your config.php you can enable query strings:

```
$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;
```

The access  to the method using this url:

```
http://www.myserver.com/?id=1234
```

I think that should work.

Comment: Is it possible to do it without enable the $config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE; ? http://www.myserver.com/1234

Answer (score 0):

On your route.php file

```
// Would leave as your default controller
$route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';

// But add get query route here 
$route['number='] = 'welcome/index';
```

You need to have **?** at the start of the query get and then after that any other url query use **&**.

And then on controller

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->helper('url');

        echo anchor('?number=1234', 'Home', array('target' => '_blank'));

        // http://www.example.com/index.php/?number=1234

        echo '</br>';

        echo $this->input->get('number');

        $this->load->view('welcome_message');
    }
}
```

When refresh page you should be able to see the anchor link which you can click on then will open new page and should display the numbers.

You also may come up with error disallowed uri

Then go to config and use `?&=`

```
$config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:_\-?&=';
```

You could alt use uri segments

```
<?php echo $this->uri->segment(1);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use remap function

```
<?php

defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {

    public function _remap($method, $params = array())
    {

        if (method_exists($this, $method))
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, $method), $params);
        else
            return call_user_func_array(array($this, 'index'), $params);    
    }
    public function index($number)
    {
        //$this->load->view('welcome_message');

        echo get parameter here = 1234
    }

}
```